# Delete mail based on subject from outlook by power shell script

Tags: powershell

I wrote a script to delete particular mails from particular outlook account but it's not deleting mails based on mail subject . Can anybody tell me what is wrong in my code

**CODE**

```
    $Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
    # Delete an Email from the folder Inbox with Subject Title &quot;Action&quot;
    $EmailInFolderToDelete = $Outlook.Session.Folders.Item(1).Folders.Item("Inbox").Items
    $EmailInFolderToDelete | ft SentOn, Subject, SenderName, To, Sensitivity -AutoSize -Wrap 
    $EmailToDelete = $EmailInFolderToDelete | Where-Object {$_.Subject -eq "Test mail";}
    $EmailToDelete.Delete()
```

It's not showing the desired result and not deleting the particular mail from particular outlook account . Can anybody help me on this .

Comment: You must be getting some errors?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code on this hey scripting guy [blog post.](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-data-mine-your-outlook-inbox/) It worked just fine.

```
$olFolders = “Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.olDefaultFolders” -as [type]

$outlook = new-object -comobject outlook.application

$namespace = $outlook.GetNameSpace(“MAPI”)

$folder = $namespace.getDefaultFolder($olFolders::olFolderInBox)

$emailToDelete = $folder.items | Where-Object {$_.Subject -eq "Test mail";}

$EmailToDelete.Delete()
```